# UIButtons not enabling other buttons

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5

Through the awesome help of people on this board I am almost done my app for my students!  I was able to make a toolbar appear over the keyboard that has a previous and next buttons.  I then made the buttons go between three input fields.

If the user starts in the first field they can go back and forth between all the fields, just like I thought you would if they use the prev/next buttons.  However, if the user was on text field three and then clicks on the first field, the buttons stay as they were and then don't work right.

```
-(void)keyboardWillShow:(id)sender{
    if ([inputA isFirstResponder]) {
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:NO];
    } else if ([inputB isFirstResponder]) {
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else if ([inputC isFirstResponder]) {
        [nextButton setEnabled:NO];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

... cycles through the next text fields

```
-(void)nextField:(id)sender{
    if ([inputA isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputB becomeFirstResponder];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else if ([inputB isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputC becomeFirstResponder];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
        [nextButton setEnabled:NO];
    } else if ([inputC isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputB becomeFirstResponder];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

... cycles through previous text fields

```
-(void)previousField:(id)sender{
    if ([inputC isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputB becomeFirstResponder];
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else if ([inputB isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputA becomeFirstResponder];
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:NO];
    } else if ([inputA isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputB becomeFirstResponder];
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

In my keyboard code, the previous button calls previousField, and the next button calls nextField.  I figured that when I did the keyboardWillShow, I was setting the different inputs as first responder, but that is only on the first run through.

Is there a way to make it so when the user clicks on the field it becomes the first responder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things I can suggest:  first, do it DRY: "Don't Repeat Yourself".  Anytime you see the same code over and over, move it to a method.  Secondly you didn't specify who calls keyboardWillShow.  Check in your nib that it is being called by each inputX upon EditingDidBegin.  So the shorter code would be:

```
-(void) setPrevNextButtons {  //ensures that Prev/Next buttons are correct for current firstResponder
    if ([inputA isFirstResponder]) {
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:NO];
    } else if ([inputB isFirstResponder]) {
        [nextButton setEnabled:YES];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
    } else if ([inputC isFirstResponder]) {
        [nextButton setEnabled:NO];
        [previousButton setEnabled:YES];
    }
}

-(void)keyboardWillShow:(id)sender{
    [self setPrevNextButtons];
}

//goes through the different text fields
-(void)nextField:(id)sender{

    if ([inputA isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputB becomeFirstResponder];
    }else if ([inputB isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputC becomeFirstResponder];
    }    
    [self setPrevNextButtons];
}

-(void)previousField:(id)sender{
    if ([inputC isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputB becomeFirstResponder];
    } else if ([inputB isFirstResponder]) {
        [inputA becomeFirstResponder];
    }
    [self setPrevNextButtons];

}
```

If you felt like being tricky, you could also do this:

```
-(void) setPrevNextButtons {
    [previousButton setEnabled: [inputB isFirstResponder] || 
                                [inputC isFirstResponder]  ];
    [nextButton setEnabled: [inputA isFirstResponder] || 
                            [inputB isFirstResponder]  ];
}
```

Comment: thanks so much.  I like the DRY statement!  Will definitely think about that in the future.  I will try the code tonight and see if I can make it work.  Thanks again!

Comment: it worked!  But since I am new at this I have another question.  When you talk about my nib, I am not sure about that.  I am using Xcode 4.3 and I don't see a nib anywhere.  I see that when I am on the storyboard, I can drag the button next to editingdidbegin to the storyboard, but I don't see how I could hook it up to keyboardwillshow.  Thanks for the ideas!

Comment: Sorry, the NIB file is the predecessor to the storyboard concept. You translated my suggestion correctly into the modern world of 5.x! When you control-drag from editingdidbegin to the viewController, you should see an option to connect it to the SentEvent keyboardWillShow

Answer (score 1):

As for triggering the updating, `UITextField` has a delegate method `-textFieldDidBeginEditing:`, which you could use to call `-setPrevNextButtons` as proposed by @mackworth. Several other methods exist that do similar things—see the [related delegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UITextFieldDelegate) for more information.

For instance, try this controlling code in the text field's delegate:

```
- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    if (textField == inputA || textField == inputB || textField == inputC)
        [self setPrevNextButtons];
}
```

It should go without saying that you'll have to set the delegate for the text fields for this to work.

Comment: Taldar, I wish I could give both of these answers a check. And I can't one up anything yet.  But this solved the updating just like you said.  Thanks so much.